# Show files from ftp server in angular app

Tags: angular, ftp, ftp-client

a few days ago i saw these two sites https://www.monstaftp.com/demo/ and https://www.filestash.app/de/ftp-online-client.html

I have an angular app in which the files have to be downloaded from an ftp server by the user and uploaded again in the app.

After seeing these two pages that work with angularjs and react, I'm sure that my requirements must also be implemented in angular

I just have to connect to an ftp server and display the files, optionally filter and sort them to choose one. After that the filestream should be stored to the database.

is that doable?
I have already tried ftp-client and basic-ftp but failed both times.
do you have an approach or a tutorial for me? I've been looking for days now.

The App uses Angular 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do FTP purely from a client side app, you would need a server component to do this, an example of which is the Filestash API